When converting simulation to mesh, is there any way to use less particles?
I am wondering if there is a feature in blender that allows you to control the number of particles you use to bake mesh.
The thing is, I'm making very thin stream of water pouring down using fluid simulation but there are always tiny splashes happening around the stream (even though it's not hitting anything) and I don't want to convert those extra bits to mesh.
Cranking up the resolution division in Physics tab and making inflow object smaller might be a solution but I can't set more resolution due to machine spec limitation, so I was wondering if there is other way.

Say for example, a feature that lets you ignore particles groups that are less dense.
